# Transformer - I connected 50k resistance which burnt - why? AC

Tags: transformer, ac, high-voltage, amperage

Wall supply gives as much power as a component uses.
I'm trying to connect a 800W transformer to produce an arc of electricity. But I can't exceed 10A because home fuse will triger (so every device will be instantly cut from electricity etc).
So I want to know, what will be the amperage, should be 800W/230V = 3.48A right?

However what causes the transformer to be 800W - it doesn't drain energy directly as a bulb does. It produces electromagnetic field and the "amount" of this field is indicated by number of scrolls I guess, but is it also increased by it's resistance?

I want to be sure that adding 1M*2 resistance would make it drain P=I^2*R, I=(800/2M)^(1/2) = 1/50 = 0.02 A and that wall supply won't somehow try to compensate 2M resistance and increase amperage to like 800A.

To do so, I connected an analog amperage meter 0-1A and a 47k ohm resistor, it should be I = (800/47000)^(1/2) = 0.13 A. And U = 6132V. 
When I connected 2M ohm, nothing has happened, it should have been U = (800*2M)^(1/2) = 40k V right? Maybe then increased 10 times as it's a MOT, 1000:100, so 400k V... But the resistors didn't burn.

Why did 47k burn and 2M not, in spite of 6k vs 40k voltage?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDTDJr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Used MOT:
MD903-EMR-1
Class 220,
230V 50Hz

I didn't count the turns on each coil, but because it's supposed to give over 2k V output, I guess it has 100:1000 ratio, considering one of the coils is really thicc and the other is rather thin, eye-estimation that is.

Also it might be a 900W not 800W

Comment: 800W transformer means that *it* will burn (or trip some protection) if connected to something drawing more than 800W. It's a maximum rating

Comment: I suggest you stop experimenting until you know what you are doing.

Comment: Don't stop experimenting. Just stop experimenting with things that could burn your house down or kill you if you get them wrong.

Comment: Well I'm doing it quite carefuly when it comes to touching AC wires... the transformer could begin burning, but I connect it to power supply for very short time to see what happens... Also houses have protection from over 15A-20A amperage: fuse triggers and electricity is cut, so I don't think wall wires would burn, unless I drained something like 1000A, and this is why I asked my question...

Comment: @ThePhoton I can't count the number of dangerous things I've done and still do. (Nitroglycerin manufacturing, fireworks manufacturing, rocket fuel experimentation together with custom nozzle designs I've done, using boiling sulfuric acid in a condensing boiler used to liquify rocket fuels for loading into chambers, 100% concentration insecticide research requiring two syringes of atropine kept on my side in case of exposure, ... and that's just the more unusual stuff and doesn't count stuff like common forestry work taking down trees, etc.) I just might make it a few more years, yet ;)

Comment: @jonk I bet you *know* what you are doing...

Comment: @jonk, but did you first study and do smaller-scale experiments so you would know what you were doing when you did the dangerous stuff?

Comment: ***I always do a substantial literature search until I feel like I understand the risks well.*** Even when a teenager. But I've had my share of "events." Red phosphorus + potassium chlorate mixture went off in my hand, while demonstrating to a classroom; saving the filter paper used to purify mercury fulminate crystals (recrystalized using glacial acetic acid) for later testing accidentally blew up a table and a few cabinets and some glassware. I can't pretend to be risk-free in what I do and I can always use another eye and brain helping out. Still, if you don't die, you do learn more. ;)

Comment: My worldview is risk-*mitigation* (as much as can reasonably be done) but not risk-*avoidance*. Avoiding risk means not doing or learning. Mitigating risk means being prudent about doing and learning, but to greatly improve the odds that one can keep on doing and learning more stuff.

Comment: @Immo: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar and there's a transformer symbol. Add a schematic so we know how you've wired this. Mark the transformer primary and secondary voltages on it too.

Comment: Microwave Oven Transformers produce some 2000V on the secondary, with serious current behind it, too. A mistake working with those things can easily be the last mistake you ever make. Judging from your questions, you do not have a good grasp of basic electrical engineering. And that's fine! But please experiment with something safer. Get a 12V power supply and then you can still experiment with Ohm's law and burn resistors, but without electrocuting yourself.

Comment: @Transistor https://imgur.com/jo3S79v something like this

Comment: @marcelm but for a transformer I need AC not DC and the power supplies I looked at were DC only I think... Do you recommend any brand or type? Also, maybe some cheap used Function Generator would do the same job but also allow to set the shape of signals?

Comment: @immo: The image belongs inline in your question, not as a link elsewhere buried in your comments. The image doesn't show the transformer winding rated voltages. It seems as though you might be using a **step-up** transformer from a microwave oven but there is no mention of this in your question. Please edit the question to make it very clear what your setup is. Again, what you are doing is very dangerous and your question is missing essential details which suggests that you don't know what is important and are putting yourself at great risk.

Comment: btw well, at school I studied mainly chemistry, biology, physics; now some coding languages and you are right that I don't have a good grasp of circuits, I mean: I can calculate them using various fancy methods, but the practice is different, I think that the missing key is Power which I don't really get. Thanks for your answers everyone!
I'm thinking about making some plasma-jet emiter with controled frequency using arduino microcontroler, so before I get to 1M V tesla I wanted to try sth smaller that won't shot 1m arcs to reach me on isolated area...

Comment: If you need AC to experiment, then modern power supplies (which are switch-mode power supplies) are unlikely to help. Older power supplies though usually employ a transformer that outputs a low voltage at mains frequency (potentially converted to DC by a rectifier bridge plus capacitor). Those could be very useful for you. Try looking for older wall-warts (that are fairly heavy, unlike modern ones), or maybe old halogen transformers. If you want to buy one, look for one that is specified to work off your mains voltage and mains frequency and outputs some safe voltage (<30VAC) on the secondary.

Comment: @Transistor hmm yes I use transformer from a microwave, I wanted to use a MOT tag... give me some time as I need to find out what are winding rated voltages etc..

Comment: @Transistor He does mention MOT (Microwave Oven Transformer) in his question ;)

Comment: @Immo your question has false assumptions.  Low R raises power , P= V²/R  when that occurs then you can calculate I.  A short circuit may draw as much as 10x the rated power or 8kW.   To get more current out, you must rewind and use low secondary turns ratio . No load current is < 10% due to excitation current for the iron core. e.g. A soldering gun has only 1 secondary turn.

Comment: I'll re-read all comments again tomorrow, as now I can't look at display anymore (tired eyes). Thanks again! There's a thing I'll try to figure out but... which one of the power supplies available in schematics Editor here is a wall supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what you are asking, but I will go for the question in the title of the question.

The power dissipated in a resistor is
$$P_R = V_R^2/R$$
where \$V_R\$ is the voltage across the resistor and \$R\$ is the resistor value. So, if you put \$47\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ directly across 230 V the resistor will dissipate 1.13 W. That's a lot for a common resistor, which is probably rated for 0.125 W or 0.25 W. It's no surprise that the resistor would burn up. On the other hand, if you do the same thing with a \$2\mathrm{M}\Omega\$ resistor the power dissipated is only 26 mW...it probably won't even get warm.

Answer (score 0):

As @EugeneSh mentions in comments, the rating is a maximum rating.

Power Supplies can be theoretically grouped in 3 categories

1. Constant Voltage

   A supply that is operating in constant voltage mode will vary the current that is needed to maintain a fixed voltage for load. The total (`V_SP * I_LOAD < P_MAX`)
2. Constant Current

   A supply that is operating in constant current mode will vary the voltage needed to maintain the fixed current for the load , (`V_LOAD * I_SP < P_MAX`)
3. Constant Power

   A supply that is operating in constant power mode will vary the voltage until the current into the load is the desired power (`V_LOAD * I_LOAD = P_SP < P_MAX`)

The vast majority of off-the-shelf AC power supplies operate as Constant Voltage Supplies, and the current is determined by the load. Often the max current of the device is specified as well as the power.

Many lab power supplies will let you switch from CC/CV mode

Constant power supplies are often used in applications like resistive heating, where the load is high power and can tolerate a large range of input voltages (not unusual to run resistive heating wire at 100VAC)

A passive transformer can be thought of as a constant (AC) voltage device in this context. The output voltage is fixed as a ratio of the input voltage. When the load is large the current will be high, if the load is small the current will be small The amount of current depends only on the connected load. If the current exceeds the transformer rating it will heat up and melt the wires. If the current (multiplied by transformer ratio) exceeds the input supply rating it will shut down, droop, or trip a breaker/fuse.